# Definition of "Differentia" in Lewis Carroll's Symbolic Logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am reading chapter $2$, and from what I understand, it seems like the differentia of a class is not well-defined. The book gives some definitions:

The class "Things" here refers to the class containing all the things in the universe, while Things, or things, refers to members of this (or any) set. **Adjunct** refers to a set (implied to be non-empty) of attributes, or characteristics.

> We may think of the Class "Things," and may imagine that we have picked out from it all the Things which possess a certain Adjunct not possessed by the whole Class. This Adjunct is said to be **peculiar** to the class so formed. In this case, the class "Things" is called a **Genus** with regard to the class so formed: the Class so formed is called a **Species** of the class "Things": and its peculiar Adjunct is called its **Differentia**

Suppose we create a class of all the things in the universe, which we call $U$. We specify an adjunct, $A$, which is composed of the attributes $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ ($A$ is not possessed by all things in $U$). This adjunct is peculiar to a class $C$. Suppose that all the things which possess attribute $a_n$ are in $C$. That is, there are no objects in $U$ that are not in $C$. Assuming $a_n$ is the only attribute in $A$ which contains this property (having multiple such attributes just makes the following list harrier) then, there are infinitely many adjuncts which can specify class $C$ from the universe $U$. They are:

$\{a_n\}$ (Only the objects in $C$ have the attribute $a_n$ anyway)

$\{a_1, a_n \}$

$\{ a_1, a_2, a_n \}$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\{a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n\}$

Because we did not define an adjunct to contain only unique attributes, we can also say

$\{a_n, a_1, a_1 \}$

$\{ a_n, a_1, a_1, a_1\}$

$\{ a_n, a_1, a_1, a_1, a_1 \}$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

$\cdot$

Which one of these is the Differentia of $C$?

Comment: The terminology comes from [Aristotle's Logic (and Metaphysics)](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#SpeGenDif).

Comment: "Standard" example:  let $A$ the *universe* of all "Things" made of all *Animals*: the *Genus*. Let *Rationality* the Adjunt (i.e.an attribute) peculiar to a certain sub-class of $A$ : the sub-class $R$ of "Rational animals": the *Species*. In this scenario, *Rationality* is the *Differentia* : the peculiar attribute that pick out univocally the sub-class $R$ of *rational animals* from the class $A$ of *animals*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In the book, adjunct is defined as a list of one or more attributes. Are you using adjunct and attribute interchangeably? With regard to the example, the class which you specified by the attribute "rational" can also be unequivocally specified by the set of attributes  $\{$"human",  "able to solve $2x+4=0$", and "bipedal"$\}$. It can also be specified by the set $\{$"human"$\}$, also by the set $\{$"able to solve $2x+4=0$, "bipedal" $\}$, etc.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  All of these sets are peculiar to the same class that you specified in the example. Which one of these sets (or lists) is the differentia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Chapter I](https://books.google.it/books?id=oKyln-hWnHQC&pg=PR33) :

> an "**Adjunct**" is any "**Attribute**" or any Set of Attributes.

See [Chapter II](https://books.google.it/books?id=oKyln-hWnHQC&pg=PR34) :

> A "**Class**" is formed "picking out" from the collection of all Things those Things that posses a certain Adjunct, i.e. that share a certain Attribute or Set of Attributes.

As an example, we may consider as universe of all Things the set $\mathbb N$ of all *natural numbers* and use the property $\text {Even}$ (or: "evenness") to "pick out" from it the collection of all *even* numbers.

In this case, $\text {Even}$ is the Adjunct, the single Attribute carachterizing the even numbers: Carroll call it the *peculiar* Adjunct.

> In this case, the Class "Things" [our : $\mathbb N$] is called a "**Genus**" with regard to the Class so formed : the Class is called a "**Species**" and its peculiar Adjunct is called its "**Differentia**".

Thus, with respect to the Genus $\mathbb N$ (the Class of natural numbers) the Class of even numbers is a Species defined by the Differentia "evenness".